# How to remove all specific elements from Vector

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

In fact, regarding to the title in the question, I have a solution for this, but my approach seems to waste resources to create a List objects.

So my question is: Do we have a more efficient approach for this?

From the case, I want to remove the extra space " " and extra "a" from a Vector.

My vector includes:

`{"a", "rainy", " ", "day", "with", " ", "a", "cold", "wind", "day", "a"}`

Here is my code:

```
List lt = new LinkedList();
lt = new ArrayList();
lt.add("a");
lt.add(" ");
vec1.removeAll(lt);
```

As you can see the extra spaces in the list of `Vector`, the reason that happens is that I use  `Vector` to read and chunk the word from word document, and sometimes the document may contain some extra spaces that caused by human error.

Comment: Why can't you trim (remove spaces from) the String before adding it to the vector ? i.e. trim the string after reading from the document and before putting into the vector

Comment: well i think if your "specific elements" size >1, then you need another collection (linkedlist in your example). well you can of course iterate your Vector, and with a lot of if/else to check the element and remove without using a collection.  For your problem, I think the better solution is not how to play with the Vector, but the input before it was added into vector.

Comment: If execution speed is the problem here and lt contains more elements I'd opt to use HashSet instead for lt. And of course best were not to put the elements you don't want into the vector in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach does suffer the problem that deleting an element from a `Vector` is an `O(N)` operation ... and you are potentially doing this M times (5 in your example).

Assuming that you have multiple "stop words" and that you can change the data structures, here's a version that should (in theory) be more efficient:

```
    public List<String> removeStopWords(
            List<String> input, HashSet<String> stopWords) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>(input.size());
        for (String elem : input) {
            if (!stopWords.contains(elem)) {
                 output.append(elem);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    // This could be saved somewhere, assuming that you are always filtering
    // out the same stopwords.
    HashSet<String> stopWords = new HashSet<String>();
    stopWords.add(" ");
    stopWords.add("a");
    ... // and more

    List<String> newList = removeStopwords(list, stopWords);
```

---

Points of note:

- The above creates a new list.  If you have to reuse the existing list, clear it and then `addAll` the new list elements.  (This another `O(N-M)` step ... so don't if you don't have to.)
- If there are multiple stop words then using a HashSet will be more efficient; e.g. if done as above.  I'm not sure exactly where the break even point is (versus using a List), but I suspect it is between 2 and 3 stopwords.
- The above creates a new list, but it only copies `N - M` elements.  By contrast, the `removeAll` algorithm when applied to a `Vector` could copy `O(NM)` elements.
- Don't use a `Vector` unless you *need* a thread-safe data structure.  An `ArrayList` has a similar internal data structure, and doesn't incur synchronization overheads on each call.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, a Vector may be the correct solution if you need it to be thread safe.

Comment: @Chrispix - I'm aware of that.  But the Question does not mention that the solution needs to be thread-safe, and implementing thread-safety when it is not needed is bad for performance.  Note that the Question is about performance optimization.